# Access not configured

Tags: android, google-api, gmail-api

I've properly generated the signature also I've created a project in Google in API console but I'm still getting this error 
[image: the error I'm getting]

Comment: `You have to enable it by...`   You must need the Gmail API enabled. Have you tried enabling it from the given link to you by Google? or if already enabled, haven't you tried specifying release or debug SHA1 Signature **according to your Build Type**?

Comment: My build type is release I have tried using all build types also my APIs are enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You should check your SHA1 signature in project. If it is debug build you should specify debug SHA1 signature, and if it is release build you should specify release SHA1 signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable also the Google+ API in your Developers Console and make sure that your SHA 1 key that you provide is placed in the play store. Source: [How to integrate Gmail Api in android app](http://www.mm1886.com/0430/how-to-integrate-gmail-api-in-android-app/). Also make sure or double check that you follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) in Android quickstart for Gmail API.